Translate a standard error frome R to SAS
I want to traslate some code from R to SAS.
In this piece of R code, there is a "se.fit = TRUE"
theModel <- as.formula(ifelse(timeTrend, "response~seasgroup+wtime",
                               "response~seasgroup"))
model <- glm(theModel, family = quasipoisson(link = "log"))
 
pred <- predict.glm(model, data.frame(wtime = c(kk), seasgroup=factor(1)),
               dispersion = model$phi, se.fit = TRUE)
     
eta0 <- pred$fit
seEta0 <- pred$se.fit   
 
 

I think to use a GENMOD, but what is similar to :"se.fit = TRUE"?
I tried this:
proc genmod data=observed_db (where=(t_inversa >= 27));
class seasgroup;
model &model / dist=poisson link=log scale=pearson;
output out=observed_storia
pred=pred
**what is similar?**
leverage=leverage;
store out=previsione;
ods output ModelFit=ModelFit;
run;

proc plm source=previsione;
score data=observed_db out=observed_db pred **what is similar?**  / nooffset ilink;
run;

eta0= log(pred);
seEta0= **what is similar?**/eta0  ..?..


It should be as simple as including the stderr option in the score statement. However, do note that you are currently predicting the link scale in R whereas you're working in the original scale in SAS.
